# searching products like (hats). but I have products name with (hat) in product's table in mysql. I wanted similar result with hat or hats

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I am using inner join to get data from these tables.

```
           SELECT u.user_id, u.user_full_name, u.user_picture, 
            s.shop_id, s.user_id, s.shop_name,
            p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_description, 
            p.product_image, p.product_price, p.user_id 
            FROM products AS p 
            INNER JOIN shops AS s 
            ON p.user_id = s.user_id 
            INNER JOIN users AS u 
            ON s.user_id = u.user_id 
            //this function is used to add two or more strings
            WHERE lower(p.product_name) 
            LIKE '%hats%'
            GROUP BY s.user_id
  /*  query end*/
```

Comment: just make %hat% instead

Comment: I want same result with hat or hats!

Comment: yeah but `hats` already included if you used `%hat%`

Comment: I have a product's table in mysql DB. I'm getting products' name from users, suppose an user enter a product name cap. On the other side, other user make search for (caps) on search engine, that user cannot found any caps because product caps not in the product table. If users search for (cap) on this situation users getting result.

Comment: But if %cap% that's include `caps`